# Add a Label to the bottom of a webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, tabbar, wkwebview

I am trying to add a label to a webview, the label looks like a button and sticks to the bottom of the screen, it transitions to a different view on tap.

Tried adding a tab bar to the webview but the webview does not show the tab bar at all.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved will be highly appreciated. The link below shows the green label at the bottom of the webview. I am trying to add a similar label on my webview but so far no luck.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R73S3.jpg

Comment: use this code
[[[myWebView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:myLabel];

Answer (score 0):

Don't add label to webView. WebView is responsible for drawing its content. Add over subviews above webView, e.g. to webView's superview. Especially if you need to move it to over view later.

[image: Possible views layout]

Also, want to mention that in provided design I would use UIButton instead of UILabel for "RESERVE CLASS" element.

And pay attention to AutoLayout and LayoutConstraints.